# Cannot inflate android.widget.Toolbar after using PreferenceFragmentCompat [cause: RtlSpacingHelper]

Tags: android, android-toolbar, android-inflate, preferencefragment, preferencefragmentcompat

A `FragmentActivity` that is correctly inflating `android.widget.Toolbar` stops doing so after the first deployment of `androidx.preference.PreferenceFragmentCompat`.

The stacktrace indicates the underlying cause of the failure to be a null instance of `android.widget.RtlSpacingHelper`:

```
android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #18: Binary XML file line #18: Error inflating class <unknown>

Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #18: Error inflating class <unknown>

Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:430)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:652)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:794)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:734)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:496)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:427)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:378)
    at common.WideFrag.onCreateView(WideFrag.java:168)
    at androidx.fragment.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:3104)
    at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentStateManager.createView(FragmentStateManager.java:524)
    at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentStateManager.moveToExpectedState(FragmentStateManager.java:261)
    at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.executeOpsTogether(FragmentManager.java:1899)
    at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.removeRedundantOperationsAndExecute(FragmentManager.java:1817)
    at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1760)
    at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager$5.run(FragmentManager.java:547)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:751)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6780)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1496)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1386)
    
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.RtlSpacingHelper.setDirection(boolean)' on a null object reference
    at android.widget.Toolbar.onRtlPropertiesChanged(Toolbar.java:825)
    at android.view.View.resolvePadding(View.java:16493)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.resolvePadding(ViewGroup.java:7006)
    at android.view.View.initializeScrollbarsInternal(View.java:5740)
    at android.view.View.<init>(View.java:4988)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.<init>(ViewGroup.java:579)
    at android.widget.Toolbar.<init>(Toolbar.java:291)
    at android.widget.Toolbar.<init>(Toolbar.java:287)
    at android.widget.Toolbar.<init>(Toolbar.java:283)
    ... 23 more
    
WideFrag.onCreateView: InflateException for toolbar.xml=2131558714 (0x7f0d013a): android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #18: Error inflating class <unknown>
```

The Toolbar ('toolbar.xml') is as follows:

```
<android.widget.Toolbar android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/listItemHeightMenu"
        android:background="@color/khaki_tp"
        android:elevation="6dp"
        android:visibility="gone"
        > <!-- NB: Stacktrace refers to this line -->
    </android.widget.Toolbar>
```

Here is a torn-down minimalist version of the offending Fragment. It contains its own instantiator for the convenience of anyone wishing to recreate the problem. If your app uses **android.widget.Toolbar** then it will stop working after this Fragment is run but note that **androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar** will still inflate normally!

```
package yourPackage;
import static java.lang.String.format;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import androidx.annotation.Nullable;
import androidx.fragment.app.FragmentActivity;
import androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager;
import androidx.fragment.app.FragmentTransaction;
import androidx.preference.PreferenceFragmentCompat;
import yourPackage.R;

/** Prove bug upsetting Toolbar inflation (1/2) */
public class PrefsBug1 extends PreferenceFragmentCompat {
    public static String TAG = "Buggy-tag1";

    public static void newInstance(FragmentActivity A) {
        PrefsBug1 frag = new PrefsBug1();
        int ctr = R.id.fragment_container;
        FragmentManager fm = A.getSupportFragmentManager();
        FragmentTransaction ft = fm.beginTransaction();
        ft.add(ctr, frag, TAG);
        ft.addToBackStack(TAG);
        String msg;
        try { ft.commit();
            msg=(format("Added '%s' to container %d [%s] (backstack was %d).", TAG, ctr, "R.id.fragment_container", fm.getBackStackEntryCount()));}
        catch (Exception e) { msg = e.getMessage(); }
        Log.d(TAG, msg);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreatePreferences(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState, @Nullable String rootKey) {
        setPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.pref_debug, rootKey);
    }
}
```

Here is the sample PrefScreen ('pref_debug.xml'):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<PreferenceScreen xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <PreferenceCategory android:title="A PREFERENCE">
        <EditTextPreference
            android:key="pref_fontScale"
            android:title="pref_fontScale_title"
            android:summary="Override default font scale"
            android:inputType="number|numberDecimal"
            android:defaultValue="0.0" />
    </PreferenceCategory>
</PreferenceScreen>
```

Finally, in the SDK, it is disappointing that while **android.widget.RtlSpacingHelper** is not to be found in the *android.jar* belonging to *Android API 33, extension level 3 Platform*, **RtlSpacingHelper.java** nevertheless came with the platform source.

But the real question is how the offending Fragment affects all future behaviour of the Activity and might there be a circumvention?

Comment: so why not to use androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar that works?

Comment: A retrograde step that would require re-programming over 30 modules that have otherwise run perfectly for years.

Answer (score 0):

Change your <Toolbar> XML to refer to a subclass:

```
public class ToolbarX extends android.widget.Toolbar {
    public ToolbarX(Context context) { this(context, null); }
    public ToolbarX(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) { this(context, attrs, R.attr.toolbarStyle); }
    public ToolbarX(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) { super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr, 0); }
    @Override public void onRtlPropertiesChanged(int layoutDirection) {}
}
```

(Pure unadulterated programming filth often saves the day)